# Creating Multiple Subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file to create multiple folders, but I need to create 4 subfolders in each of the folders created by the batch file.  Can this be done in the same batch file?

Comment: Yes it can. Good luck!

Comment: This may help you. . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506993/dos-batch-file-to-create-multiple-folder-and-subfolders

Answer (score 1):

#### I need to create 4 subfolders in each of the folders created by the batch file

This very easy using `md`.

Example:

```
md folder1\sub1 folder1\sub2 folder1\sub3 folder1\sub4
md folder2\sub1 folder2\sub2 folder2\sub3 folder2\sub4
...
```

---

#### Make an entire path

> MD creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
>
> For example, assuming `\utils` does not exist then:
>
> ```
> MD \utils\downloads\Editor 
> is the same as: 
>
> md \utils 
> cd \utils 
> md downloads 
> cd downloads 
> md Editor
> ```

Source [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) - Make Directory - Creates a new folder.

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.